# Hello, I am new to Java, could someone tell me how to improve this? Any tips?

Tags: java

Code:

```
package minecraft;
import java.util.Scanner;
class minecraft {
 public static void main(String[] argv) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean i = sc.nextBoolean();
  boolean isMCagoodgame = i;
  if (isMCagoodgame == true) {
   System.out.println("Minecraft is a good game!");
  } else {
   {
    System.out.println("Minecraft is a NOT good game!");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

As with the title, I am looking for some improvement on this code. Thanks for reading and have a great day!

Comment: You can start with proper indentation. And [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place for such questions anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that probably would make this more organized.

Comment: You can replace the whole method with one line: `System.out.println("Mincraft is a " + (new Scanner(System.in).nextBoolean() ? "" : "NOT ") + "good game!");`

Comment: Also, never compare `== true`; it's redundant and offers an opportunity for typos.

Comment: Your class should be called `Minecraft` (with capital "M"), following the generally accepted convention that the name of a Java class should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you go through Oracle [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) on Java Code Conventions which is crucial for beginners.

Speaking of your example, one-liner (called ternary operator) suggested earlier might be good, but it tends to decrease readability in a more complex code chunks.

As far as I'm concerned, you don't need to declare two variables for the task you're trying to do. You will want to be rational about creating variables. They should bring a purpose to the code otherwise there's no need for them. And stick to more meaningful names because you will definitely refer back to them puzzled at the names you've given them and what should they do.

Answer (score 0):

In general, these tips may help:

1. Always keep class name (first letter be capitalized) and variables Camel case. (CamelCase is a naming convention in which a name is formed of multiple words that are joined together as a single word with the first letter of each of the multiple words capitalized so that each word that makes up the name can easily be read.
   source: https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/CamelCase)
2. Name the variables meaningful. Don't use single letter. Anyone who looks at your code should understand what you are trying to do.
3. Proper indentation
4. Avoid unnecessary code. Keep code short and simple. Example , you can use ternary operator instead of **if else** if executable code is single line.
5. Sometimes it is okay to use extra variable if it makes your code more readable.

   ```
   class Minecraft {
      public static void main(String[]argv) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String message;
         boolean isGoodGame = input.nextBoolean();
         message = isGoodGame ? "Minecraft is a good game!" : "Minecraft is a NOT good game!";
         System.out.println(message);
      }
   }
   ```